# Multi dataset drop down list in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is it possible to create one drop down list for more than one dataset and query according to the selected parameter from the drop down list.

For e.g. 
  If I  have a two datasets,

**Dataset_1 values:**

- Person_ID
- Name
- Address

**Dataset_2 values:**

- Product_ID
- ProductName
- Price

Now what I am trying to do is add both dataset's ID to drop down list. When I choose `Person_ID`, report should show only dataset_1's value and vice versa.

Comment: What are the fields of the main report? the main report shows all the values?

Comment: It depends if I choose Dataset_1 from drop down list then report should show all the fields of Dataset_1 and vice versa.